# How to move a file and undo file deletion in vim :Explore?

Tags: vim, vi

I play around with native file explorer in VIM (`:Explore`) and faced with two unresolved issues:

1. How to move a file?
2. How to undo file deletion (`D`)?

It seems VIM delete files permanently and I can't undo this action. As well as I can't find information how to move a file. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You move by renaming. For example, you can rename `~/pictures/cat.gif` to `~/videos/cat.gif`.
2. There isn't a way.